# send header request with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have to call a web service from angularjs. When calling this web service operation it is necessary that the HTTP header contains OT-Authentication and looks like this:

```
GET 'url'

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

**OT-Authentication: 'auth_token'**

Host: 'host'

Connection: Keep-Alive

User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

I tried with this angularjs code:

```
$scope.products=[];

$http.get(url,{headers:{"OT-Authentication":auth_token}},{cache:true}).success(function(response){
$scope.products=response.data;});
```

and this produce HTTP OPTIONS request instead of GET request and the request header looks like this:

```
Host: 'host'

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

**Access-Control-Request-Method: GET**

**Access-Control-Request-Headers: ot-authentication**

Origin: 'url'
```

What should i do to produce GET request with the necessary request header?

Comment: mmm the Options is  like an hand shake for front end and back end..if it doesn't work after options maybe it could be a CORS problem .. ahve you enabled cors on back end?

Comment: Also the server must respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` which includes `OT-Authentication`. For more information, see [MDN HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers).